# I chipped my back tire, should I get it replaced?

Tags: tires, bmw, sidewall-damage

I was coming through a drive through at a restaurant and I did not see there was a little corner hidden and chipped off the back sidewall tire. I didn't immediately check the tire out till I got back home and I didn't feel anything wrong with the car while I drove it on the highway that night.

I'm so mad at myself for letting this happen as I'm usually careful and I just got both my back tires replaced this past summer and don't drive much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If no cords showing, you are good.

Comment: Oops Sorry I thought I did reply back, but thanks everyone for the help. It did help me. I also did get someone to look at it and they told me it was fine as well. I couldn't get anyone at the time when I asked this question because they were busy and I was scared to drive it then. Thanks! Riding this out till its time to change : )

Answer (score 1):

This **looks** superficial based on the image, so it should be ok to keep.

But, keep an eye on it and, take the opportunity to get it checked by a professional...